# count on multiple boolean columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

My Current Table looks as follows

```
public.transactions

storeId     FeatureA  FeatureB  FeatureC  Details
123         true      false     false     ... (JSON)
123         false     false     false
123         true      false     true
```

basically the transaction table tracks the specific feature that triggered the transaction. I need to grab the count for each feature for a specific id, something like this:

```
storeId     FeatureA  FeatureB  FeatureC
123         2         0         1
```

I've been getting the count doing 3 individual counts

```sql
Select *
FROM public.transactions
where "storeId" = 123 AND "FeatureA" = true
```

but the seems really inefficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you just want conditional aggregation?  Postgres makes this easy by supporting the `filter` clause:

```
select storeid,
       count(*) filter (where featureA) as num_featureA,
       count(*) filter (where featureB) as num_featureB,
       count(*) filter (where featureC) as num_featureC
from public.transactions t
group by storeid;
```

Answer (score 3):

With conditional aggregation:

```
select storeid,
  sum(case when featurea then 1 else 0 end) featurea,
  sum(case when featureb then 1 else 0 end) featureb,
  sum(case when featurec then 1 else 0 end) featurec
from tablename
group by storeid
```